# asp.net c# select multiple listview entrys like in dropbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, select, dropbox

I have a Listview showing multiple file entys of a folder in my filesystem. I want to make multiple entrys of that ListView selectable just like in dropbox to select file fpr move, delete, etc.

This is my ListView at the moment:

```
<asp:ListView ID="fileListView" runat="server" OnItemCommand="fileListView_OnItemCommand">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton id="downloadFile" runat="server" cssclass="fileListTitle" CommandName="downloadFile" CommandArgument='<%# Session["filePath"].ToString() + Eval("fileName").ToString() %>'><img src="img/download.png" class="downloadButton" alt="herunterladen" /><%# Eval("fileName")%></asp:LinkButton>
<%--                <a class="fileListTitle" href="<%# Session["filePath"].ToString() + Eval("fileName").ToString() %>" target="_blank" >
                    <img src="img/download.png" class="downloadButton" alt="herunterladen" /><%# Eval("fileName")%></a>--%>
                    <asp:Label CssClass="fileListSize" ID="fileSize" runat="server"><%# Eval("size") %></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label CssClass="fileListDate" ID="creationDate" runat="server"><%# Eval("cDate") %></asp:Label>
                    <div class="fileListMenu">
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" cssClass="fileEditButton" ToolTip="Umbennen" CommandName="renameFile" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("fileName") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" cssClass="fileDeleteButton" ToolTip="Löschen" CommandName="deleteFile" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("fileName") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

I want the same function as they use in Dropbox where I have just selected some entrys:
[image: dropbox multiple row select]

Comment: DropBox uses a *lot* of JavaScript.  I wouldn't expect to be able to mimic its functionality strictly with native WebForms server-side controls.

Comment: Put a checkbox in your ItemTemplate...

Answer (score 0):

So you write a bit of javascript so that when each row is clicked, some suitable value is stuck in an array and the row is highlighted. If people click an already highlighted row, you unhighlight it and remove the value from the array. You write the array to a comma separated list, stick that in a hidden field and when the form submits, split the comma separated list to get the values you want for each row.